# C# Calling two classes that have the same interface

Tags: c#, inheritance

How can I call two methods that have the same interface? I've got a background service that read messages from a kafka queue by calling `ConsumeMessagesFromQueue`.

```
public class InboundWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IKafkaConsumer _kafkaConsumer;

    public InboundWorker(IKafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer)
    {
        _kafkaConsumer = kafkaConsumer;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await _kafkaConsumer.ConsumeMessagesFromQueue(stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

This is the interface:

```
public interface IKafkaConsumer
{
    Task ConsumeMessagesFromQueue(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

I've got a class with that interface:

```
public class KafkaConsumer : IKafkaConsumer
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public KafkaConsumer(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
    }

    public async Task ConsumeMessagesFromQueue(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to return and process data from another kafka queue as well. So I was thinking of creating another class that also implements the interface above `IKafkaConsumer` like so:

```
public class KafkaConsumerB : IKafkaConsumer
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public KafkaConsumerB(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
    }

    public async Task ConsumeMessagesFromQueue(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

With my ioc set up like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IKafkaConsumer, KafkaConsumer>();
services.AddSingleton<IKafkaConsumer, KafkaConsumerB>();
```

However with the changes above mentioned, `ConsumeMessagesFromQueue` gets hit for `KafkaConsumerB` but not `KafkaConsumer`.

How can I get both methods to be hit? Rather than using the same interface (`IKafkaConsumer`) for `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaConsumerB`, if I create another interface that's an exact duplicate of `IKafkaConsumer` but say `IKafkaConsumerB` for `KafkaConsumerB`, and register it, then both methods get called how I'd like. Since both interfaces are duplicate, I'm hoping to simplify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use both implementations of the interfaces then you can inject them using an IEnumerable.

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IKafkaConsumer> _kafkaConsumer;

    public InboundWorker(IEnumerable<IKafkaConsumer> kafkaConsumer)
    {
        _kafkaConsumer = kafkaConsumer;
    }
```

Then call the methods using a foreach loop.